# which layout should i use for making a table type layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-framelayout

I want to make layout like this:

[image]

Can anyone guide me which layout is more suitable?(I have fix number of rows and columns).

Relative layout or linear layout? or something else?

Comment: You can use TableLayout , GridLayout  or RecyclerView with GridLayout Manager It is depends on your requirement

Comment: if you have fixed rows & column, then use linear layout. If the number of rows/column varies from server result, then use table layout

Comment: Yes i have fixed rows and columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code for the design you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#8FDFBF"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title1"
            android:text="title1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_title1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#8FDFBF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title2"
            android:text="title2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_title2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="21"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#4ADCA1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title3"
            android:text="title3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_title3"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="25 c"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#4ADCA1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title4"
            android:text="title4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_title4"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="40 mb"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#9EFAD5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title5"
            android:text="title5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_title5"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="50 %"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#9EFAD5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title6"
            android:text="title6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_title6"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="90 %"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```